# AgentWork access to LiveChatTranscript

Tags: query, chat

I am working with the AgentWork object. Which is an object that relates the Id of an agent with the field UserId and Its associated work with the field WorkItemId.

In this case the works are chats, the object is LiveChatTranscript. The LiveChatTranscript object has a field Status.

I am doing a loop over all my agentworks and I need to count the LiveChatTranscript when its Status is 'Canceled' or 'Missed'. When I perform the following query

> SELECT Id, OwnerId,**WorkItem.Status** from AgentWork

The field Status is empty, I am doing it correctly?? Is there anyway to make that query.

A lot of thanks in advance